# Can't pull out the information from object using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working (for the first time) with scraping a website. I am trying to pull the latitude (in decimal degrees) from a website. I have managed to pull out the correct parent node that contains the information, but I am stuck on how to pull out the actual number from this. All of the searching I have done has only told me how to pull it out if I know the string (which I don't) or if the string is in a child node, which it isn't. Any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
a_string = soup.find(string="Latitude in decimal degrees")

a_string.find_parents("p")
Out[46]: [<p><b>Latitude in decimal degrees</b><font size="-2">
(<a     href="definitions.html#LAT" target="_blank"><u>see definition</u></a>)
</font><b>:</b> 35.7584895</p>]

test = a_string.find_parents("p")

print(test)
[<p><b>Latitude in decimal degrees</b><font size="-2"> (<a 
href="definitions.html#LAT" target="_blank"><u>see definition</u></a>)</font>
<b>:</b> 35.7584895</p>]
```

I need to pull out the 35.7584895 and save it as an object so I can append it to a dataset.

I am using Beautiful Soup 4 and python 3

Comment: If an answer meets your requirements you should, please, mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that, since you have used the `find_parents` method (plural), `test` is a list. You need only the first item of it.

I will simulate your situation by doing this.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = '<p><b>Latitude in decimal degrees</b><font size="-2"> (<a href="definitions.html#LAT" target="_blank"><u>see definition</u></a>)</font><b>:</b> 35.7584895</p>'
>>> item_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
```

The simplest way of recovering the textual content of this is to do this:

```
>>> item_soup.text
'Latitude in decimal degrees (see definition): 35.7584895'
```

However, you want the number. You can get this in various ways, two of which come to my mind. I assign the result of the previous statement to `str` so that I can manipulate the result.

```
>>> str = item_soup.text
```

One way is to search for the colon.

```
>>> str[1+str.rfind(':'):].strip()
'35.7584895'
```

The other is to use a regex.

```
>>> bs4.re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)', str).groups(0)[0]
'35.7584895'
```

Comment: Thank you @BillBell! That worked. But one question, how did you know that it was a list? All I could find was that it was a bs4.element.ResultSet but nothing I found could explain what that was...

Comment: I think you're looking at `.groups(0)[0]`. That's a method for the result from the *regex* search. There's only one group in the regex, it's `(\d+\.\d+)`, and I know that these search results are returned as lists, so I chose the first, ie, the 0th one.